# insert single value across multiple columns in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with almost 27 columns(all of integer datatype) with first column being ID(PK).
I wish to update all the values to some value say 500. 
is there any query to update without typing all the 27 column names like this.

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET a=500,b=500,c=500.....z=500 where ID = 1
```

Or else can i make any PL/SQL function which will fetch next next column by itself without providing the column name and set the value ?

Comment: AFAIK this is the only option, unless you want to use dynamic SQL.  If so, then you might be able to loop over all columns and assign `500` to each one.

Comment: But as a side note, 27 columns sounds a bit on the large side.  You might want to restructure your database.

Comment: by dynamic SQL, yu mean PL/SQL ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in a single query. You need to specify column names in UPDATE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to UPDATE all columns of a record without having to list every column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926765/how-to-update-all-columns-of-a-record-without-having-to-list-every-column)

Comment: Refer below link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079617/update-multiple-columns-in-sql

Comment: PL/SQL is Oracle only (not mysql as tagged) and no that's not what is meant by dynamic sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is not possible in any db's**. You need to mention the column names. Check the update specifications for most common db's mentioned in the below thread

[How to UPDATE all columns of a record without having to list every column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926765/how-to-update-all-columns-of-a-record-without-having-to-list-every-column)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this. You always have to specify the column names while updating. If it is a proccess You will be reapeating You can write stored procedure doing it.