# Replace all null values of a schema with 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to update all null values of a specific SCHEMA with 0. What is the easiest way of doing it, since I have many tables/columns?

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE [mySchema].[test1](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
    [ClassCode] [int] NULL,
    [ClassValue] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_test1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) 

CREATE TABLE [mySchema].[test2](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
    [ClassCode] [int] NULL,
    [ClassValue] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_test2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) 

INSERT INTO test1 (ParentID,ClassCode,ClassValue) VALUES (100,1,NULL)
INSERT INTO test1 (ParentID,ClassCode,ClassValue) VALUES (100,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO test1 (ParentID,ClassCode,ClassValue) VALUES (100,1,2)
INSERT INTO test1 (ParentID,ClassCode,ClassValue) VALUES (100,NULL,2)

INSERT INTO test2 (ParentID,ClassCode,ClassValue) VALUES (100,1,NULL)
INSERT INTO test2 (ParentID,ClassCode,ClassValue) VALUES (100,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO test2 (ParentID,ClassCode,ClassValue) VALUES (100,1,2)
INSERT INTO test2 (ParentID,ClassCode,ClassValue) VALUES (100,NULL,2)
```

Result should be:

Test1

```
+----+----------+-----------+------------+
| ID | ParentID | ClassCode | ClassValue |
+----+----------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |      100 |         1 |          0 |
|  2 |      100 |         0 |          0 |
|  3 |      100 |         1 |          2 |
|  4 |      100 |         0 |          2 |
+----+----------+-----------+------------+
```

Test 2

```
+----+----------+-----------+------------+
| ID | ParentID | ClassCode | ClassValue |
+----+----------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |      100 |         1 |          0 |
|  2 |      100 |         0 |          0 |
|  3 |      100 |         1 |          2 |
|  4 |      100 |         0 |          2 |
+----+----------+-----------+------------+
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926765/how-to-update-all-columns-of-a-record-without-having-to-list-every-column

Comment: There may not be a silver bullet way to do this.  Different columns are generally different beasts, have different types, etc.

Comment: ISNULL around all your columns. You can even do it dynamically by querying information_Schema.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this - null indicates no value exists but 0 indicates a value of 0 exists - not the same thing.

Comment: @P.Salmon That's what I said at first, but that's the requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically create the statement from SQL Server metadata table (`information_schema.columns`) filtering:

- by schema (`your_specific_schema` in the code sample)
- by datatype (probably numeric data types)

Here is a sample code:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) =''

select @sql = @sql + 'update [' + table_schema + '].[' + table_name + ']'
              + ' set [' + column_name + '] = 0 where [' + column_name + '] is null' 
              + char(10)
from information_schema.columns
where data_type in ('int','bigint') --ad all numeric types you want to set to 0
    and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_specific_schema'
print @sql
```

Output should look like this:

[image]

Once you have checked the generated script you can execute it:

- with copy & paste and then with <kbd>F5</kbd>
- or you can execute the statement directly from the variable `@sql` appending this statement to the query above:

  ```
  exec (@sql)
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Below script will generate an update statement to update all null values with 0.

```
SELECT 'UPDATE ' + TABLE_NAME + ' SET [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] = 0 WHERE [' + 
COLUMN_NAME + '] IS NULL'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
-- WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOURTABLENAME'
```

Uncomment the last line to do generate the script for a specific table.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have one more question though. This will create all the update statements, how will I execute them?Should I save it to a file and execute the script?

Comment: Hi Chriz, you can run it in SSMS or any other Query Window or run via program. Your choice.